# Quel est le masculin de « Mademoiselle » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre-biologique, société

En ces temps de lutte pour l'égalité entre les hommes et les femmes, les féministes demandent la suppression du terme « mademoiselle » (entre autres expressions purement féminines).

Je me demande si dans un souci d'équité on n'aurait pas pu demander à utiliser le même terme pour les hommes, s'il existe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ceux qui se [posent](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090209033137AAcLzQK) [cette](http://www.forum-metaphysique.com/t4950-madame-ou-mademoiselle-monsieur-ou-mondamoiseau) [question](http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070727073421AAWnSum) [utilisent](http://blogfeministe.skyrock.com/3034350401-Mademoiselle-mondamoiseau-bonjour.html) [souvent](http://www.courtois.cc/blogeclectique/index.php?post/2006/01/10/63-mon-damoiseau) *[mondamoiseau](http://www.google.be/search?q=mondamoiseau)*.

Comment: Ne devrions nous pas plutôt nous calquer sur demoiselle? Ce qui donnerait [mondemoiseau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_name#Madame.2C_Mademoiselle.2C_Monsieur).

Comment: J'y pensais aussi, mais _[damoiseau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/damoiseau)_ existe, _demoiseau_ pas. Cela dit, _damoiseau_ n'a pas la signification d'homme non encore marié, donc il ne convient pas tant que ça.

Comment: @Joubarc J'ai l'impression que *demoiselle* n'a pas toujours été rattaché spécifiquement à l'état de non-marriage. On dirait même que *damoiseau* a été rattaché à l'état de non-chevalier (voire est disparu de l'usage courant) avant que cette association n'apparaisse définitivement pour *demoiselle*.

Answer (score 2):

Il est à noter (comme le dit Circeus) que l'utilisation courante du mot a changé au 20ème siècle. En France on à fini par ne plus donner de titre noble à qui que ce soit et de ce fait le sens premier à disparu.

Avant le mot signifiait "femme sans titre" ("noble non titrée" pour rester convenable.) Donc toutes les femmes en France sont maintenant des demoiselles! D'un autre coté, cet usage était certainement quelque peu péjoratif.

> "Si vous écrivez à une personne qui a 
>   un titre honorifique,vous le mentionnez : 
>   Monsieur le baron ^ Monsieur le comte. Si 
>   c'est à un homme non titré, vous mettez 
>   simplement Monsieur."

(Source: http://www.archive.org/stream/cihm_36736/cihm_36736_djvu.txt )

Comment: Monsieur pour un homme non titré, ou pour le frère du roi.